# How to set default mime-tipe for any file extension in Tomcat 6?

Tags: tomcat, mime-types

Mime-types are specified in Tomcat's conf/web.xml file.
It's look like this:

```
<mime-mapping>
   <extension>txt</extension>
   <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Previously I try following:

```
<mime-mapping>
   <extension>*</extension>
   <mime-type>application/octet-stream</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

but it doesn't help me.
How to specify default mime-type for any file extension?

Comment: * is not a valid extension. you'll have to specify the extensions you want special encoding, else the default is taken as text/html.

Comment: How I can change default "text/html" value to something like this "application/octet-stream"? Thanks.

Comment: Testing with Tomcat 7 I discovered if you remove all the mime-mapping entries then the actual response will NOT include the Content-Type header at all.  The web browser will look at the content and translate it to text/html if it sees <html> tags in the content.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no way. You need to explicitly set them yourself. A servlet filter is a suitable place for this.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

I however highly question the business need for this. It's only disadvantageous for SEO and the client. If your sole purpose is to pop a *Save As* dialogue, then you should say that so. There are much better solutions to achieve this than forcing a wrong mime type.

Comment: Thanks! Filter is that I need. I use it to set default content type "application/octet-stream". If content type is not specified, then client's app crashes due to http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6806893

Comment: Agreed, forcing MIME types in order to trick browsers can be a dangerous game.