# Font-face not working in IE7/8 on Windows Vista and 7 (XP works fine!)

Tags: css, font-face

Im using font-face to use some nice fonts in my website. 
The CSS is as follows:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "TheSansSemiBold";
  src: url("/fonts/thesans-semibold-webfont.eot#") format("embedded-opentype"),
  url("/fonts/thesans-semibold-webfont.woff") format("woff"),
  url("/fonts/thesans-semibold-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"),
  url("/fonts/thesans-semibold-webfont.svg#webfontcnxqsBPR") format("svg");
}
```

Now, this works fine in all browsers when visiting the page with a PC on Windows XP. But when visiting the same page on a PC with Vista or Windows 7 the font is not used, as if it's not found..

I've cleared the cache and all browser history multiple times, but it doesn't solve it..

I've never come across some CSS issue which was OS related.. So what is wrong with my code?

Any ideas?

Edit: Nobody with a clue? I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a example at the moment :(.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following mimetypes in IIS:

```
.eot (application/octet-stream)
.woff (application/octet-stream)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it doesn't work yet. Im using a tomcat webserver so I followed the steps in another answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282867/how-to-set-default-mime-tipe-for-any-file-extension-in-tomcat-6 But it doesn't fix it. (No errors / exceptions, it just won't show on IE7/8 on Vista/7) Am I missing something. (still +1 for the good direction!)