# Tomcat MIME type for file with no extension

Tags: tomcat, mime-types, tomcat8

Is it possible with Tomcat to specify/change the MIME type sent for files that don't have an extension?

Answer (score 1):

No way to do that as in the mapping of conf/web.xml in tomcat you need to provide the extension. However you could maybe try something from your application like having a servlet filter. e.g:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Check [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282867/how-to-set-default-mime-tipe-for-any-file-extension-in-tomcat-6) post.