# How to fix default content-type rendering issue in apache-tomcat-8.5.39?

Tags: css, jsp, tomcat, svg, tomcat8.5

I am setting up my application to test with latest apache-tomcat-8.5.39. When I am trying to load my application on any web browsers few of my resources are not loading properly.

Few resources are not loading properly because of the content-type returned by the web server.

These resources are local resources (taking from servers) :
ex:

**CSS**:

Request URL: http://localhost:8080/workflow/css/wfstyle.css
   *Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8*

**SVG**:

Request URL: http://localhost:8080/workflow/images/svg/Delete.svg
   *Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8*

But all *CDN* are loading properly

Request URL: https://cdn.abc.ocm/assets/1.5.1/css/abc-design-system-ltr.css
   *content-type: text/css*

This is how I am adding SVG to JSP pages:

```
<span class="esg-icon__container">
   <img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/svg/Delete.svg"></img>
</span>
```

And CSS to JSP:

```
<%
    if(request.getLocale().getLanguage().contains("ar")){
%>

<link href="https://cdn.abc.ocm/assets/1.5.1/css/abc-design-system-rtl.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/abc-design-system-rtl-custom.css" />

<% } else { %>

<link href="https://cdn.abc.ocm/assets/1.5.1/css/abc-design-system-ltr.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/abc-design-system-ltr-custom.css" />

<%}%>
```

web.xml from tomcat:

```
<mime-mapping>
     <extension>svg</extension>
     <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Expected content-type

For CSS:
   *content-type: text/css*

For SVG:
   *content-type: image/svg+xml*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set default mime-tipe for any file extension in Tomcat 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282867/how-to-set-default-mime-tipe-for-any-file-extension-in-tomcat-6)

Comment: Also, I want to know, why it's happening only with the latest build of tomcat and not with earlier versions?

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain ) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String charEncoding = "UTF-8";
        String contentType = "image/svg+xml;";

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;

        String file = request.getServletPath();

        if(file.contains(".svg")){
            if(!contentType.equals(servletResponse.getContentType())) {
                servletResponse.setContentType(contentType);
                servletResponse.setCharacterEncoding(charEncoding);
            }
            if(!charEncoding.equals(servletRequest.getCharacterEncoding())) {
                servletRequest.setCharacterEncoding(charEncoding);
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
```

**And it worked:**

> Content-type: image/svg+xml; UTF-8;

Is this a good practice? If no is there any other way of doing the same thing?

I am using Java1.8 and Strust1.2.